# Windows Phone 7 when set in German language option seems to break float.parse, how to fix?

Tags: windows-phone-7, global

I've discovered that float.parse behaves differently when Windows Phone 7 is set to run in German language. It does not parse a '.' as a decimal point, apparently it's supposed to parse ',' as decimals instead.

I looked online and found the solution is supposed to be as follows:

float val = (float)double.Parse("123.123", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat);

Except that doesn't work, it still incorrectly parses it and the '.' is ignored.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Tag `german` removed as part of the [**2012 cleanup**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are in the German culture, then the correct behaviour is to interpret "123,45" as "123.45".

If you want the app to use the "." regardless of the current culture, then use:

```
float val = (float)double.Parse("123.123", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
```

However, this might confuse your German users!